# Can't install extension in php.ini to use sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I've installed PHP and add the following lines in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64
```

The dll files are stored in my `c:\php\ext` folder
When I run `phpinfo`, I can see `SQLSRV`, `SQLSRV` support enabled and the version number.

When I try to run my code

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I get an error:

> call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: you can try with full path, for example `extension=C:\Program Files\php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
 extension=C:\Program Files\php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll`

Comment: One of the usual: wrong php.ini edited, not restarted Apache/mod_php, not looked at the log files.

Comment: I'm new to php.Do I have to rename one of the two php.ini files?

Answer (score 0):

no there is no need to use the full path to the extensions.

In addition to the `sqlsrv` dll file in your php extensions folder which you already have (I hope you are using the right version for your system architecture, php version and thread safety) you need one of these drivers:

Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows (SQL Server® 2005):
      https://www.microsoft.com/zh-CN/download/details.aspx?id=36434
Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server® - Windows + Linux (SQL Server® 2016)
      https://www.microsoft.com/zh-CN/download/details.aspx?id=50420

you can verify that the extension is loaded by your php by loading a page with `phpinfo()`.